# Проблема с потоками c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

впервые работаю с потоками и возникла проблема в синхронизации.

Имею следующий код:

```
typedef int Request;
std::mutex                       g_mutex;
Generator                        g_gen(150,100);
bool                             RequestIsExpecting=true;
int ReqAdded = 0;
int ReqNeed= 10;
std::deque<Request> ReqQueue;
int FailReqCount = 0;
int ReqLimit = 48;
void AddRequest();
void AddRequest();
bool RequestIsExpecting=true;
std::deque<Request> ReqQueue;
void Worker(int& ReqAcceptedCount)
{
    while(RequestIsExpecting || !ReqQueue.empty())
    {   
        if(ReqQueue.empty())
            continue;
        Request WorkTime;
        g_mutex.lock();
        WorkTime = ReqQueue.front();
        ReqQueue.pop_front();
        g_mutex.unlock();
        ReqAcceptedCount++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(WorkTime));
    }
}
int main()
{
    int Worker1ReqCount = 0;
    std::thread Worker1(Worker,std::ref(Worker1ReqCount));
    int Worker2ReqCount = 0;
    std::thread Worker2(Worker, std::ref(Worker2ReqCount));
    
    AddRequest();
    RequestIsExpecting = false;

    if (Worker1.joinable())
        Worker1.join();
    if (Worker2.joinable())
        Worker2.join();
    std::cout << Worker1ReqCount;
    std::cout << Worker2ReqCount;
}


void AddRequest()
{
    while (ReqAdded != ReqNeed)
    {
        if(ReqQueue.size()>=ReqLimit)
        {
            FailReqCount++;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(g_gen.next()));
            continue;
        }
        g_mutex.lock();
        
        ReqQueue.push_back(g_gen.next());
        ReqAdded++;
        g_mutex.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(g_gen.next()));
    }
}
```

С одним "рабочим" программа работает нормально, ошибка возникает при появлении второго рабочего в коде. Видимо, напутал где-то с мьютексами в функции Worker или что-то не сделал дополнительно.

[image: ошибка]

Comment: "ошибка возникает..." Какая ошибка? Где в вопросе приведено подробное описание ошибки? И что это за странные множественные определения `std::deque<Request> ReqQueue;`? Это невозможно скомпилировать.

Comment: @AnT добавил картинку ошибки.  Request это тот же float, добавил его в код сверху. Generator - класс для генерации случайных чисел от нижней до верхней границы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые обращения к общему контейнеру должны быть огорожены мьютексом. Представьте, что в то время, пока делается `pop()`, вы начали проверять `empty()` - результат будет "как повезет".